# How did this email bypass my SPF settings?

Tags: linux, spam, spf, email, spoofing

I received a phishing email this morning that appeared to come from one of my addresses to itself.

Looking at the headers, I found something interesting.

```
DomainKey-Status: no signature
X-Spam-Checker-Version: SpamAssassin 3.2.5 (2008-06-10) on
    mydomain.com
X-Spam-Level: 
X-Spam-Status: No, score=-1.0 required=5.0 tests=BAYES_00,HTML_MESSAGE,
    HTML_MIME_NO_HTML_TAG,MIME_HTML_ONLY,MISSING_MID,SPF_PASS autolearn=no
    version=3.2.5
Received: (qmail 10412 invoked by uid 110); 6 Aug 2012 09:59:17 -0400
Delivered-To: 18-bdstrainers@anotherOfMyDomains.net
DomainKey-Status: no signature
Received: (qmail 10390 invoked by uid 110); 6 Aug 2012 09:59:17 -0400
Delivered-To: 34-info@yetAnotherOfMyDomains.com
DomainKey-Status: no signature
Received: (qmail 10373 invoked from network); 6 Aug 2012 09:59:15 -0400
Received-SPF: pass (mydomain.com: domain of surewest.com designates 212.61.84.249 as permitted sender) client-ip=212.61.84.249; envelope-from=visualsx@surewest.com; helo=d84249.iae.nl;
Received: from d84249.iae.nl (212.61.84.249)
  by yetAnotherOfMyDomains.com with SMTP; 6 Aug 2012 09:59:14 -0400
Date: Mon, 6 Aug 2012 14:27:38 +0100
From: <info@yetAnotherOfMyDomains.com>
To: <info@yetAnotherOfMyDomains.com>
Subject: Your Federal Tax Payment ID: 8716780 is failed
X-Mailer: foljo
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: text/html;
charset=Windows-1252
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit
```

Ok, so first off, 212.61.84.249 is an IP in Nederlands, and if you [visit the IP](https://www.homelacie.com/?hipname=casper500g) you get a LaCie login page.

Next the domain [surewest.com](http://surewest.com), is digitalTV/ISP in the mid US.

but what gets me is this line in particular:

```
Received-SPF: pass (mydomain.com: domain of surewest.com designates 212.61.84.249 as permitted sender) client-ip=212.61.84.249; envelope-from=visualsx@surewest.com; helo=d84249.iae.nl
```

My `SPF` record is set correctly on my server, so;

HOW in the world did they spoof a valid `SPF` on `surewest.com` for MY domain which is NOT on surewest?

What can I do to keep this from happening again?

Comment: If I check the SPF record for surewest.com, it has +all in it which will allow anything.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your SPF record designates everyone in the world as an allowed sender:

```
"v=spf1 mx:... +all"
```

The `+all` is the important part, `+` means "allowed" and `all` really means "the whole internet".  They didn't need to spoof anything, their mail is valid according to your SPF record.  Try `-all` instead.